# Start in insert state based on minor mode

Tags: evil

I would like the org capture buffer (which IIUC is in org-capture-mode, a minor mode) to start in insert state; It seems that both the evil-insert-state-modes variable and the evil-set-initial-state function operate over major modes (or at least, when I run org-capture after modifying the former or calling the latter, the buffer that opens up does not start in insert state).

Does anyone ahve any suggestions?

Comment: The library `org-capture.el` has an `org-capture-mode-hook` -- so you would just do the standard thing we do for all other hooks.  Something like this -- `(defun my-org-capture-load-fn () [INSERT EVIL STUFF HERE]) (eval-after-load "org-capture" '(progn (add-hook 'org-capture-mode-hook 'my-org-capture-load-fn) ))`  I've never played with evil-mode, so I cannot help you with the specific line for enabling the feature you seek.

Comment: `(add-hook 'org-capture-mode-hook 'evil-insert-state)` seems to work. If you want to write up an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem as I wanted the annotation contents editor of PDF-tools to start in insert mode. For that case a working solution is to add `pdf-annot-edit-contents-minor-mode` to the list of `evil-insert-state-modes` using `M-x customize-variable`. So just add the correct minor-mode to that list.